# How do you go through ArrayList and find what is in the ArrayList using Scanner?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am making an ArrayList of cars and I am having trouble how to iterate through the ArrayList and print what I ask using a scanner.
Example: I am looking for an Audi in the list, I want it to look through the ArrayList and if it is in the ArrayList print "We have a %s."

This is what I have so far:
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> car = new ArrayList<>();
    car.add("Audi");
    car.add("Chevrolet");
    car.add("Dodge");
    car.add("Ford");
    car.add("Honda");
    car.add("Toyota");
    car.add("Volkswagen");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();

    for(String name: car)
    {
        if(name == sc){
            System.out.printf("We have a %s.", sc);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: A string cannot be equal to a scanner. It can be equal to the string that you read with the scanner though. And hint: List has a contains() method.

Comment: `if(name == sc){`, No, you're trying to equate a String with a Scanner object, so that doesn't make logical or coding sense. You use the Scanner to extract Strings from a file or the user and then do things with the String.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I am new to java lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that real problem here<sup>1</sup> is that you don't have a clear understanding of what a `Scanner` does.

A `Scanner` *reads* characters from a stream (for example `System.in`) and turns them into various kinds of values; e.g. integers, floating point numbers, strings and so on.   The basic model is:

- call `hasNextXXX` to *test* if there is a `XXX` to read.
- call `nextXXX` to *read* a `XXX`.

So you are trying to get a name of a car manufacturer from the `Scanner`.  Assuming that car manufacturer names don't have spaces in them, what you are reading is a white-space delimited token.  The method for reading a token is `Scanner::next`.  It returns the token as a `String` with any leading or trailing whitespace removed.

Aside: `String::nextLine` would also work, except that it returns the complete line with all white space entered by the user before or after the name<sup>2</sup>.  If the user enters (for example) `Ford` with a space after it, then that won't match the value in your `car` list.  To deal with that, you would need to do something like this:

```
    String str = sc.nextLine().trim();  // 'trim' removes leading and 
                                        // trailing whitespace; e.g. SP,
                                        // TAB, CR and NL characters.
```

Once you have the name as a `String`, you should `String::equals` to compare it against other strings.  Comparing strings using `==` is **incorrect** in nearly all circumstances; see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

For a deeper understanding of `Scanner`, I recommend that you take the time to read the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html).

---

Your code doesn't do the above.  Instead, it reads a line (i.e. `str = sc.nextLine()`) and doesn't use it.  Then it uses `==` to test if the `Scanner` is equal to each `String` in your list.  That fails, because a `Scanner` is not a `String`.

Aside: in Java, `==` for a reference type (i.e. for objects) means "is this the same object".

---

<sup>1 - The other possibility is that you didn't read the code that you had written carefully enough.</sup>

<sup>2 - ... apart from the line separator sequence; i.e. CR, NL or CR + NL.  This is removed automatically by `nextLine`: refer to the javadocs for more details.</sup>